# Recording the list of applications invoked by Eclipse IDE under the hood

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I am using a customized Eclipse IDE in Ubuntu to write a C++ application (more specifically I am using the OMNET++ Eclipse IDE). Once I build the application (Ctrl + B), I can see that many applications are invoked by the IDE under the hood in order to compile/link my C++ application. I was wondering if there is any ways to see the list of (all) applications that are invoked by the Eclipse IDE in order for me to get a better understanding of what is going on under the hood?

Comment: Take a look at `htop`'s tree view.

Comment: Is `htop` reliable enough to capture all the new processes invoked by the IDE? Should I increase the refresh interval? Is there any way to record every changes into a file?

Comment: Ah. I'd be surprised if htop is capable of doing what you want. A tool to do this probably exists, but I do not know it. I will shut up now.

Comment: `strace` may help.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a configurable IDE with support for many different, underlying tools, and can be customised to invoke more/less of them with more/less/different parameters.

What you need, probably, is understanding of how C++ projects are compiled and linked in general ([How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work) is a good start), and then trying to find out exact Eclipse settings that correspond to the non-IDE steps.